# What to do when I have a placeholder type as string but a value type as number?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an input as a component in my TSX file.

```
import { InputHTMLAttributes } from "react";

interface InputProps extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
    placeholder: string,
    label?: string,
}

export const Input = ({ placeholder, label, ...rest}: InputProps) => (
    <>
        {label && <label>{label}</label>}
        <input placeholder={placeholder} {...rest} />
    </>
)
```

Although, when I try to use it to take a number value I got a problem.

```
  const [name, setName] = useState<string>("")
  const [hobby, setHobby] = useState<string>("")
  const [age, setAge] = useState<number>(0)

       <Input
          placeholder='Your name'
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          value={name}
        />
        <Input
          placeholder='Your hobby'
          onChange={(e) => setHobby(e.target.value)}
          value={hobby}
        />
        <Input
          placeholder='Your age'
          onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}
          value={age}
        />
```

The first and second inputs are working well, but my third is not. Is it a problem with my placeholder? The problem says:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'SetStateAction'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but you can try this

```
<Input
      placeholder='Your age'
      onChange={(e) => setAge( parseInt(e.target.value) )}
      value={age}
    />
```